# JFrame size is (0,0), can't change it's size

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

Im making the GUI. I created the JFrame and added 2 JPanels, using JTabbedPane.
Despite the fact that i used setSize() method, when I press "start" it creates a little window with 3 default Windows buttons, so I have to resize it by myself.

This is what my window looks like when I run the program:

[image: My Window]

This is the code I'm using which produces the results in the image:

```
JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("crm");
frame.setSize(750, 600);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
JPanel qw = new JPanel();
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650,500));
frame.add(tabs);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.setLayout(null);
panel.setPreferredSize(frame.getSize());
tabs.add("1", panel);
tabs.addTab("2", qw);

frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Works fine for me.  What version are you on?  (I'm on 1.8.0_111)

Comment: Call `setVisible()` _after_ `add()`. Don't use `null` layout. If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.